# errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound" for AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I found this error while testing my Lambda function. I have given the export.handler function in my index.js but still I am getting the errorMessage "index.handler is undefined or not exported"

## .

```
'use strict';

var Alexa = require('ask-sdk-v1adapter');
var constants = require('./constants');
var languageStrings = require('./resourceStrings');
var voiceCodeHandlers = require('./voiceCodeHandlers');
var secureHandlers = require('./secureHandlers');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.appId = constants.appId;
  alexa.debug = constants.DEBUG;
  alexa.dynamoDBTableName = constants.dynamoDBTableName;
  alexa.resources = languageStrings;
  alexa.registerHandlers(
    voiceCodeHandlers.newSessionHandlers,
    voiceCodeHandlers.codeStateHandlers,
    voiceCodeHandlers.changeCodeHandlers,
    voiceCodeHandlers.newCodeHandlers,
    voiceCodeHandlers.helpStateHandlers,
    secureHandlers
  );
  if (alexa.debug) {
    console.log("\n" + "******************* REQUEST **********************");
    console.log("\n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  }
  alexa.execute();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports.handler` instead of `exports.handler`